# Just some integral confirmation.

Tags: proof-verification

I have a first order differential to solve;

$$\frac{dr}{d\theta}=\cot\theta \cdot r$$

I have solved it to get this in explicit form;

$r = B\sin\theta$ where $B$ is an arbitrary constant.

I just like for someone to tell me whether i am correct or not please.

Comment: looks fine to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>If $f=B\sin\theta$ then $\dfrac{dr}{d\theta}=B\cos\theta$.  Is it true that $B\cos\theta = \cot(\theta r)=\cot(\theta B\sin\theta)$?  Notice that as $\theta\to0$ we have $\cot(\theta B\sin\theta)\to\infty$ (unless $B=0$) (here I'm not distinguishing between $+\infty$ and $-\infty$ but rather with the $\infty$ that is approached if you go in either of the two directions), and $B\sin\theta\to 0\ne\infty$.</s>

The question has been altered since I wrote what appears above.
$$
\frac{dr}{d\theta} = r\cot\theta
$$
If the line immediately above this was intended, then I would write
$$
\frac{dr}r = \frac{\cos\theta\,d\theta}{\sin\theta} = \frac{du}u
$$
so
$$
\log_e |r| = \log_e|u| + C = \log_e\sin\theta + C,
$$
and hence
$$
r = B\sin\theta.
$$
This actually leads to $B$ being a **nonzero** constant, but since we divided by $r$, we must consider separately the case where $r=0$.  And checking by substitution shows that $B=0$ also works.

So the solution of the revised question is correct.

Comment: I'd just like to make sure... your saying my answer is correct?

Comment: No; I'm saying it is not.  But now I see you've changed the question.  I read what I took to be $\cot(\theta r)$, but now it looks as if you meant $(\cot\theta)r$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Sorry, i should have made it clear, the way i originally posted it was misleading. Thanks so much.